# javascript "this" keyword in object still Refers to the window object

Tags: javascript, object, this

i'm trying to "play" with the **this** keyword, 
in order To understand it better.
i create an object name "car" with propertie "onRoad", that his value is function as you can see.

```
var car = {
    color: "black",
    type: "bmw",
    year: 2013,
    onRoad: function onTheRoad() {
        console.log(2017 - this.year);

        function demo() {
            console.log(2020 - this.year);
        }
        demo();
    }
};
car.onRoad();
```

the **this** keyword work great in the first function, and my output is **4** Just what I wanted.but for some reason in the "demo" function when i was expected that the output will be **7**,instead i get output of **NaN**.
i guess that There is a connection to the **this** keyword.
but i do not understand why it's not refers to the "car" object like in the "onTheRoad" function.**(the "demo" function is nested inside "onTheRoad" function)**.   Thanks in advance(:

Comment: well, that's the behaviour. You can't blame Javascript for that. it's within a function for this object.

Comment: Because calling `car.onRoad()` sets `this` to `car`, but calling `demo()` sets `this` to nothing in particular. It's *how you call a function* that determines `this`.

Comment: Pass the this as a ref, like this: demo(this); basically when you call a function javascript looks at the object which called it and assignes the 'this' reference to it(this is true except some cases like bind).

Comment: instead of writing demo() like this, bind it to the car object like this demo.bind(car)(), or demo.apply(car) Calling the function like this allows you to execute it within the context of the object car.